# Django QuerySet equivalent for SQL's between and

Tags: django

Let's say I have the following table:

Employee

```
name      start_date       end_date
John      2009-10-10       2009-12-31
Joe       2009-12-01       2010-05-10
```

I also have a `curr_date` = '2009-11-01'.  If I want to get all employees where `curr_date` should be between an employee's `start_date` and `end_date` inclusive, the corresponding SQL is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM employee
WHERE curr_date between start_date and end_date
```

The corresponding Django QuerySet I came up with is:

```
Employee.objects.filter(start_date__lte=curr_date, end_date__gte=curr_date)
```

Is there an alternate way to do the above with Django's QuerySet, the `__range` method doesn't quite work for the above case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the `__range` method won't work, so no, there is no way to use the Django ORM to create the SQL you are after.

Is there a problem with using the `.filter` method which you came up with?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the filter, I was just wondering of maybe a DRYer way of performing this query, I guess you can't really DRY everything.